# Django annotate not working with two apps

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two applications in my project. Models.py of first app has model:

```
class repair(models.Model):
   site = models.ForeignKey('second.site')
   price = models.FloatField()
   …
```

Models.py of second app has model:

```
class site(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

When I  do in shell:

```
repair.objects.values('site__name').annotate(sum_site=Sum('price'))
```

i am getting all items of repair model with their prices:

```
<QuerySet [{'site__name': 'Site-1', 'count_ss': 1500.0}, {'site__name': 'Site-2', 'count_ss': 1500.0}, {'site__name': 'Site-1', 'count_ss': 800.0}, {'site__name': 'Site-1', 'count_ss': 230.0}, {'site__name': 'Site-2', 'count_ss': 90.0}]>
```

How I can group by site?

Comment: try `repair.objects.values('site__name').annotate(sum_site=Sum('summ')).order_by()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

neverwalkaloner is answered in comment:

```
repair.objects.values('site__name').annotate(sum_site=Sum('price')).order_by()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate **sites** instead of **repairs**.

```
site.objects.annotate(sum_site=Sum('repair__price'))
```